# IBM Datastudio how to export/unload and import/load multiple tables with SQL?

Tags: sql, database, db2, export, ibm-data-studio

I'm having issues using the normal sysproc.admin_cmd I thought we should use, as I get error SQL3001. It says I should put the file location of the export to bcufenc folder, but I can't find it, maybe because it is data studio client on my machine.

I was hoping to get pointed in the right direction on this, or another way to export/unload and import/load

I just want to transfer data from one table to a table with the same structure in another state or scheme, as in the columns are the same, I just need to transfer the data.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `sysproc.admin_cmd` is a stored procedure running on the server. It doesn't have an access to the client's file system unless it's accessible from the server via network share. "... to a table with the same structure in another state or scheme" - what does it mean? Is the target table in the same database as the source table? If yes, then why not just to use insert/select? If no, then you can export tables to the server's file system with this SP, or to the client's file system with db2 `export` utility (you need to install db2 client on your workstation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If source and target tables are in the same Db2 database, consider using the `LOAD FROM (<query>)` variant of [`ADMIN_CMD`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html)

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('LOAD FROM (SELECT * FROM T1) OF CURSOR INSERT INTO T2')
```